# Software do not open xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The excel file saved under .xlsx do not want to open on another computer fitted with 2010 office version? The file keeps hanging and I cannot change the file format to .xls?

Comment: Just Covert [Here](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/xlsx-to-xls/) at your Convenience.

Comment: How are you transferring the file? Could the transfer media be damaged?

Answer (score 0):

Either something with this file is wrong, or your office has a problem.

To verify its the file, see if this particular file can be opened on at least 3 pc's.

If its just one file that you can't open, save/copy it again. If multiple .xslx files won't open, it is likely a problem with your install of Office.

If that's the case, I recommend executing a repair installation.

To do this, do the following:

Go to `Control Panel` > `Programs and Features`

Find Microsoft Office 2010 in the list of programs.

At the top, there's a button called remove/change, something along the lines. Press it, and the uninstall wizard will give you an option to repair your install. It has 2 options, a quick and slow method. The slow one will remove and reinstall office, but keep your settings. First, try a quick repair, and if that fails, use the slow method.

The Quick repair should take approximately 10 minutes, where the slow one can take up to 30-40 minutes.